# Get status of nested children in Vue components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to working with VueJS and components and I'm building a nested checklist for a project with an unlimited amount of levels.

The nested lists are going to be collapsable, so I want to display a status on the parent of each list. Green if all children (and childrens-children etc) are checked, yellow if only some of them are checked.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to check for this in Vue without my regular javascript solution of looping through every item every time. I feel like there has to be a cleaner and less intensive solution.

In the following code snippet you can see that I'm using a method "childstatus" on the component, to check for the status on the first set of children, but that doesn't go all the way down. In the example you'll see Subitem 1-3-1 is checked, Subitem 1-3 is yellow, and I want Item 1 to be yellow as well. Items within lists can be moved and new ones can be added, so I would like this to work as automatically as possible, without looping through all the items every time, since these list can become quite long and deep.

```js
Vue.component('checkin-list', {
  template: `
       <draggable :element="'ul'" class="checkin__list" :list="checklist" :options="{group:{ name: 'dragger' }}">
            <li v-for="(item,index) in checklist" :key="item.id">

                <div class="checkin__item" :status="childstatus(item)">               
                    <input type="checkbox" v-model="item.check">
                    {{ item.naam }}
                </div>

             <checkin-list :checklist="item.checklist" :mode="mode" :type="type"></checkin-list>
            </li>
  </draggable>
 `,
  props: {
    checklist: Array
  },

  methods: {
    childstatus: (item) => {
      let info = {
        children: false,
        checked: false,
        children_all_checked: false,
        children_some_checked: false
      };

      if (item.check) {
        info.checked = true;
      }
      if (item.checklist.length) {
        info.children = true;

        if (item.checklist.some(x => x.check)) {
          info.children_some_checked = true;
          if (item.checklist.every(x => x.check)) {
            info.children_all_checked = true;
          }
        }
      }

      if (!info.children) {
        if (!info.checked) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      } else {
        if (info.children_all_checked) {
          if (info.checked) {
            return 5;
          } else {
            return 4;
          }
        } else if (info.children_some_checked || info.checked) {
          return 3;
        } else {
          return 2;
        }
      }

    }
  }
});




var items = {
  "results": [{
    "id": 1,
    "naam": "Item 1",
    "check": 0,
    "checklist": [{
      "id": 2,
      "naam": "Subitem 1 - 1",
      "check": 0,
      "checklist": []
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "naam": "Subitem 1 - 2",
      "check": 0,
      "checklist": []
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "naam": "Subitem 1 - 3",
      "check": 0,
      "checklist": [{
        "id": 5,
        "naam": "Subitem 1 - 3 - 1",
        "check": 1,
        "checklist": []
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "naam": "Subitem 1 - 4",
      "check": 0,
      "checklist": []
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 7,
    "naam": "Item 2",
    "check": 0,
    "checklist": []
  }]
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    checklist: items.results
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul { list-style: none; }

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.checkin__list {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkin__item[status="1"],
.checkin__item[status="5"] {
  background-color: #abeab4;
}


/* green */

.checkin__item[status="3"],
.checkin__item[status="4"] {
  background-color: #f6f5a7;
}


/* yellow */
```

```html
<div id="app">

  <checkin-list :checklist="checklist"></checkin-list>

</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.6.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.Draggable/master/dist/vuedraggable.js"></script>
```

or check the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8b1yfj0x/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I did not solve my question in a way that I was originally thinking, I did create a solution.

I rewrote the function so the id of the level 1 parent is always available in it's (nested) children. When a child updates, it emits an event while mentioning that id. On the main element, a Vue method then starts at that id and works its way down all its children to determine the status. When anything changes, I just emit that change again.